# Proxy settings for zypper on OpenSuse Leap 15

Tags: opensuse, proxy

I am using OpenSuse Leap 15.0 with KDE environment on a desktop that is connected to the LAN at my institute. The institute uses a proxy and the settings the system administrator asked to use is:

```
HTTP proxy: 172.16.0.1, port 3128.'
```

FTP proxy, SSL proxy and SOCKS host have the same settings. An authentication is also required i.e. I have a username and a password.
I am connecting to the internet using `Network manager`.

I can browse websites perfectly using Firefox as the proxy settings and my username and password are saved in `Firefox -- Preferences -- Network proxy -- Settings`. However, whenever I try to use the OpenSuse package manager Zypper from the terminal, it fails to connect to any repository. After looking up this problem over the Internet, I understood that this is due to issues with proxy. The proxy settings are not applied globally.

I tried to set up the proxy through `Yast -- Network services -- Proxy`, but there proxy URL's are required which I don't have. I also tried to do the same through `System settings -- Network -- Proxy`. I chose the `Manually specified proxy` option and entered the proxy server details though there was no field for entering username and password. But immediately afterward, If I open `System settings -- Network -- Proxy`, I find that the system has automatically reverted back to `No proxy`.

Can anyone please guide me in setting up the proxy globally so that Zypper and other programs can connect to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `Yast -- Network services -- Proxy`.

The url you need is simply `http://` + "your proxy ip" + `:` + "your proxy port" + `/`.

In your case, it is `http://172.16.0.1:3128/`.

P.S. Probably you should disconnect and reconnect to have your environment updated.

Comment: Thank you! With your settings, zypper has started working! However, in Yast there is no place for SOCKS proxy. Is it alright without that?  Should I edit the file \etc\sysconfig\proxy with the url written in this way to include SOCKS proxy? I was wondering if instead of using Yast, one just chooses to edit the \etc\sysconfig\proxy then how is the username and password entered?